# Get the directory in which the script exists

Tags: unix, tcl

I'm writing a Tcl script, and I want to get the directory where the script is saved (*Not* the current dir, so `$env(PWD)` is not what I want).

Is that possible?

Comment: Who's this "we" paleface? ;-)

Comment: All of we right-thinking people of course ;)

Comment: @Tom Zych LOL! I think it's the same "we" that people both here and also on Wikipedia use, when they disagree with me. It's never "I disagree"; it's "we disagree with you". The Lone Ranger

Comment: Well, in my case tongue was firmly in cheek (in the last comment; I was moderately serious about calling directories directories instead of "folders").

Answer (score 4):

When the script is executing directly, you use:

```
set theDir [file normalize [file dirname [info script]]]
```

This *must* be run at the top level of the script or inside a `namespace eval` (where you should use `variable` instead of `set` for technical reasons). In particular, it should not be placed inside a procedure and invoked later because by that point the `info script` call will return something else. Thus, a typical package implementation script might look like this:

```
namespace eval ::samplePackage {
    variable theDir [file normalize [file dirname [info script]]]
    source $theDir/foo.tcl
    source $theDir/bar.tcl
    load $theDir/grill[info sharedlibextension]
    package provide samplePackage 1.0
}
```

If this is the main application, you can also use `$::argv0` in place of `info script`. That will not change throughout the run of your code (unless you manually set it).

Comment: The `file normalize` is there so that you can use the `cd` command safely. You don't need it if you never change the process's current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

Use [info script](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/info.htm#M34) combined with [file dirname](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/file.htm#M13)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very much up to speed with tcl (anymore)

You'd get the script name as `$argv0`

I'd simply apply the functions/utilities `realpath` followed by `dirname` to get it's directory

Answer (score 0):

```
file normalize [file dirname [info script]]
```

won't work reliably if you call a script through a *relative* symlink. I use this to mitigate possible problems:

```
proc script_dir {} {
    set r [info script]
    if {![catch {file link $r} symlink]} {
        set r [file join [file dirname $r] $symlink]
    }
    return [file dirname [file normalize $r]]
}
```